# ETrade OAuth callback URL

Tags: python, oauth, etrade-api

I am writing an app against the ETrade API. I am following [this guide](https://us.etrade.com/ctnt/dev-portal/getContent?contentUri=V0_Documentation-DeveloperGuides-Authorization) to authorize my app to my account. I can successfully get the request token and authorization URL. At the moment, I print the URL and copy/paste it into my browser. This requires copy/pasting the verification code into my app. I would rather programmatically open the URL and use a callback to receive this code.

The app is meant to run locally, not from a public web server. What is an appropriate callback URL? Can I use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`? If so, how to I receive the consumer key? Do I need to accept an HTTP request on `localhost` inside a HTTP server?

Comment: You can normally use `localhost`, the callback is just a HTTP redirect. So the local browser would be redirected to the webserver running on the same host.

Comment: @AChampion So I still need to register `localhost` as the call back with the OAuth provider, correct? And I will have to set up a basic HTTP server to handle the callback request?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Hey did you find a way to do it? If so can you share the code?

Comment: @rko It has been so long since I was working on this that I don't remember. I think I got stuck at this point and never returned to this project. Since then I came across pyetrade which does a lot of what I had in mind for my own project. You can see its github here: https://github.com/jessecooper/pyetrade.